# A dilogarithm identity?

Tags: logarithms, hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions, polylogarithm

I'm wondering whether there any nice identities (or relationships) that can simplify or possibly compact the following expressions:

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(\beta e^{\alpha x}) - \operatorname{Li}_2(\beta e^{-\alpha x}) $$

and

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(pe^{\alpha x}) + \operatorname{Li}_2(qe^{\alpha x}) $$

Comment: These are both essentially $\text{Li}_2(a)+\text{Li}_2(b)$. It seems rather optimistic to be able to simplify that.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown I'm also not positive -- just hoping $e^{ax}$ might do magic.

Comment: As far as the first one goes, you can get a hybrid between a Clausen function and a dilogarithm.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(\beta e^{ix})-\operatorname{Li}_2(\beta e^{-ix})=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\beta^k}{k^2}(e^{ikx}-e^{-ikx})=2i\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{\sin(kx)}{k^2}\beta^k$$

Assuming $\beta$ and $x$ are real, we may use Euler's formula to deduce that

$$\operatorname{Li}_2(\beta e^{ix})-\operatorname{Li}_2(\beta e^{-ix})=-2\Re(\operatorname{Li}_2(\beta e^{ix}))=2\Re(\operatorname{Li}_2(\beta e^{-ix}))$$

And I don't see any hope for anything better for this one or the other.

Comment: Thanks. Yes $\alpha$, $\beta$ and $x$ are all real. I do not see $\alpha$ in your work though. Could not you have $\alpha$ in your expressions?

Comment: @JohnButler If $\alpha$ is purely imaginary, then $\alpha x\mapsto ix$ i.e. there is no need to have both $x$ and $\alpha$.

Comment: It's indeed pure real.

Comment: :P I couldn't find anything interesting there.

Comment: Sorry I have to remove this question soon and ask it in a better ways to avoid unnecessary works. Thanks though. I re-ask it here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2386332/a-dilogarithm-identity-simplification-compaction

Comment: @JohnButler ...you should [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2383308/edit) your questions instead of reasking them...